# Новый пользователь в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, users, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Как в СУБД PostgreSQL создать нового пользователя с паролем и назначить его на одну из БД?

P.S. Версия СУБД - 9.1, пользуюсь GUI-утилитой pgAdminIII.

Comment: man createuser
    man createdb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делаем так:

- запуск pgAdmin III
- соединение с сервером
- правый клик на Login Roles
- выбор New login role
- заполнение имя и пароль
- принятие.

Можно и из командной строки, например, Ubuntu:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser пользователь
sudo -u postgres psql
```

и

```
postgres=# \password пользователь
```